# Remover borda da janela WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Estou com esta janela com uma imagem definida como *background*, ok, porém note que a imagem não está ocupando toda a janela.
De qual maneira poderei remover essas bordas?

Lembrando que, a janela está com as seguintes propriedades no XAML:

```
AllowsTransparency="True" 
WindowStyle="None" 
ResizeMode="NoResize" 
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
```

> [image: WPF window image background issues]

Answer (score 1):

Olá, O recurso que você pretende manipular pode ser chamado de duas formas.

**Em Controles**

Alguns controles do `WPF` já possuem a propriedade `Border`.
*Ex:* ListBox, Button, GridView.

Controles com esta propriedade podem ter a espessura manipulada através do atributo `BorderThickness`, a cor de borda através do `BorderBrush` e a "curvatura" através do `BorderRadius`.

**Border (Controle WPF)**

Existe dentro do WPF um controle de nome `Border` que aceita apenas um "elemento filho" e contém os mesmos atributos acima citados: `BorderBrush, BorderThickness e BorderRadius`. É **Importante** ressaltar que caso você queira usar vários elementos dentro de um Border, é recomendado usar um grid ou outro "Painel/Container" e dentro deste inserir os controles que deseja. Exemplo Abaixo:

WPF:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" BorderRadius="15">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Title"/>
        <Textbox/>
    </Grid
</Border>
```

> Para mais informações sobre **o controle Border** [clique aqui.](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.border.borderthickness?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_Border_BorderThickness)

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/138404)

Comment: isso responde literalmente a pergunta.

Comment: Creio que você poderia melhorar sua resposta explicando a mesma.

Comment: existe um atributo chamado bordertrickness na janela, só precisa setar seu valor como 0, o que existe pra explicar?

Comment: ele representa a espessura da borda, quando recebo o valor 0, ele remove ela.